# $resource not updating the view

Tags: view, resources, angularjs, updates

I have a very simple resource as follows:

```
angular.module('ExampleServices', ['ngResource']).

        factory('NoteService', function($q, $rootScope, $resource){
        var baseurl = "/api/v1/note/";
        var Note = $resource(baseurl, {}, {

            // get notes method    
            get_for_model: {
                method: 'GET',
                params:{user: '', object_id: ''},
                isArray: false
            },

            // leave note method
            leave_note: {
                method: 'POST',
            }

        });
        return Note
    }
);
```

And within a controller i call the `leave_note` method as follows:

```
$scope.note = function(){
        $scope.note = NoteService.leave_note({
            desc: desc,
            title: title,
            object_id: oid,
        }); 
    }
```

This basically calls the POST method to my applications rest API and the objects get created. Once the page is refreshed i can see the note listed in the `notes`. But as to my knowledge `$resource` should update the view on its own.

**Quote from the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)**

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

I am not able to use `$rootScope.$apply` within the `leave_note` method until i define it as a function (as follows:)

```
leave_note: function(){
    var note = New Note();
    note.desc = desc;
    note.title = title;
    note.object_id = oid;
    note.$save();
    $rootScope.$apply();
}
```

but in the above case the call send to the REST api has an `undefined` request method.

Another problem that i can think of is that I don't have `$scope.note` defined but have `$scope.notes` which is the list of notes sent by the REST api. So maybe `$scope.note` is being updated but as i am not rendering the `note` object but rendering `notes` using `ng-repeat` in the templates i am unable to see the changes in the template.

I also tried re-fetching the notes object once a new note is saved, but it basically removes all the notes and then re-render all of them which looks ugly (almost like a page refresh).

What I am trying to achieve is as soon as a `note` object is saved, i want the new note to be merged into existing notes. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: downvoter ? Please explain your downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$rootScope.$apply`, your miss understood the `$resource` API docs.

As the `$resource` documentation mentions: *"Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data."*. This means that when you do `$scope.notes = NoteService.get_for_model();` you are asking for `$scope.notes` to be populated with the (future) data received from the `NoteService.get_for_model` GET request. The `$resource` API will be responsible for doing exactly that - update the `$scope.notes` model - nothing more. Note that it **does not mention** that your data will be updated automatically when you do a POST on that same service.

If you want to update your `$scope.notes` model after adding a new note (POST), and don't want to request the entire notes list, try adding the new note directly to your `$scope.notes` model on the POST *success* callback:

```
 var note = NoteService.leave_note({
            desc: desc,
            title: title,
            object_id: oid,
        }, function() {
            $scope.notes.push(note.$get());                
        }
 );
```

Note that this can be greatly improved (i.e. avoid the `$get`) but since I don't know the exact details of your implementation I've just provided a generic solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to respond. I actually did end up using `$scope.notes.push(note)` and it does update the data. Cheers !